# UDP-запрос к серверу STUN (пример на C++)

Tags: c++, qt, udp, nat, p2p

Покажите, пожалуйста, пример C++ кода (или, оптимально, на Qt), в котором клиентский софт запрашивает по UDP STUN-сервер и получает в ответ свой внешний IP:порт.
Так, у меня есть аккаунт на стун/турн сервере quickblox.com и вот данные этого аккаунта:

- USERNAME: quickblox
- CREDENTIAL: bbceb21ba7a92d71e21fb898fda5f3e2
- API endpoint: https://api.quickblox.com
- Account ID: 45301
- Account KEY: Xgp3BXDcumuwIsktB6KS
- Auth secret: jqaeXBCH3GeUwzP

Помогите написать простейший запрос к нему.

Comment: Вы бы конфиденциальные данные убрали бы.

Comment: А их несколько изменил (половину знаков в каждом поле рандомно поменял на другие). Но в любом случае спасибо вам за проявленную заботу. И могли бы вы мне хоть чем-то помочь по моему вопросу, если вас не затруднит?

Comment: К сожалению, мои знания в отношении протокола STUN весьма и весьма поверхностны.

Comment: А можете подсказать что-то по UPnP или по NAT-PMP? (это второй рассматриваемый мною путь преодоления двойного NAT) Или по туннелированию через какие-то другие протоколы, например, ICMP или DNS? (это третий способ-кандидат)

Comment: Я бы если бы мог – подсказал бы. Спросите лучше на большом SO – там аудитория обширнее.

Comment: Думаю, код работы со STUN/TURN сервисами - одна из наиболее насущных проблем сегодня. Прошу, дайте кто-нибудь подсказку - вы сделаете этим много добра очень большой аудитории программеров.

Answer (score 1):

На днях исследовал вопрос соединения через два NAT-а и написал, как мне кажется, [минимальный пример](https://github.com/sercxjo/nathole-example).
Приведу часть своей программы, опрашивающую STUN-сервер.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <string.h>
#define debug(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
struct peer_addr {
    uint32_t in_addr;
    uint16_t port;
} mypeer[1];

static inline void die(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2), noreturn));
static inline void die(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, va);
    va_end(va);
    exit(1);
}
static inline void fatal(const char *name) __attribute__((noreturn));
static inline void fatal(const char *name)
{
    perror(name);
    exit(1);
}
int connect_to_host(const char *node, const char *port, int sock_type)
{
    int res;
    struct addrinfo ar_request= { 0, AF_INET, sock_type }, *ar_result= 0;
    if( (res= getaddrinfo(node, port, &ar_request, &ar_result)) != 0 )
        die("Resolving %s: %s\n", node, gai_strerror(res));
    int sockfd= socket(ar_result->ai_addr->sa_family, ar_result->ai_socktype, ar_result->ai_protocol);
    if( sockfd<0 ) fatal("Create socket");
    if( connect(sockfd, ar_result->ai_addr, ar_result->ai_addrlen)<0 ) fatal("Connect socket");
    freeaddrinfo(ar_result);
    return sockfd;
}
struct stun_header {
    uint16_t msg_type;
    uint16_t data_len;
    uint32_t magick;
    uint32_t id[3];
    unsigned char data[];
};
void stun_req(int sockfd, struct peer_addr *peer)
{
    struct stun_header buf= { htons(1), 0, htonl(0x2112A442) }; // 1 - binding request
    int rndfd=open("/dev/urandom", 0);
    read(rndfd, (char*)buf.id, sizeof buf.id);
    close(rndfd);
    for( int attemp=0; attemp<5; attemp++ ) {
        if( write(sockfd, &buf, sizeof buf) != sizeof buf ) fatal("Send STUN request");
        struct {
            struct stun_header hdr;
            unsigned char data[256];
        } rbuf;
        struct pollfd rfd= {sockfd, POLLIN};
        int ret=poll(&rfd, 1, 500);
        if( ret<0 ) fatal("STUN responce waiting");
        if( ret==0 ) continue;
        if( rfd.revents&(POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP) ) die("Error during STUN responce wait\n");
        ret= read(sockfd, &rbuf, sizeof rbuf);
        if(ret<0) fatal("Read STUN response");
        if( rbuf.hdr.magick!=buf.magick || memcmp(buf.id, rbuf.hdr.id, sizeof buf.id) ) continue;
        for( int i=0; i<ret-20 && i<rbuf.hdr.data_len && rbuf.data[i+2]==0; i+= ((rbuf.data[i+2]*256+rbuf.data[i+3]+7)&~3) ) {
            debug("%x %d\n", rbuf.data[i]*256+rbuf.data[i+1], rbuf.data[i+2]*256+rbuf.data[i+3]);
            if(rbuf.data[i+2] || rbuf.data[i+3]==0 || ((i+rbuf.data[i+3]+7)&~3)>ret-20) continue;
            void debugIP(const char *name) {
                debug( "%1$s IPv%2$d %4$d.%5$d.%6$d.%7$d:%3$d\n", name, rbuf.data[i+5]*2+2, rbuf.data[i+6]*256+rbuf.data[i+7],
                 rbuf.data[i+8], rbuf.data[i+9], rbuf.data[i+10], rbuf.data[i+11] );
            }
            switch( rbuf.data[i]*256+rbuf.data[i+1] ) {
            case 0x8020:
                for(int j=0; j<2; j++) rbuf.data[i+6+j]^= ((char*)&rbuf.hdr.magick)[j];
                for(int j=0; j<rbuf.data[i+3]-4; j++) rbuf.data[i+8+j]^= ((char*)&rbuf.hdr.magick)[j];
                debug("XOR-");
            case 1: debugIP("MAPPED-ADDRESS");
                if(rbuf.data[i+5]==1) { // IPv4 only
                    peer->port= *(uint16_t*)(rbuf.data+i+6);
                    peer->in_addr= *(uint32_t*)(rbuf.data+i+8);
                }
                break;
            case 4: debugIP("SOURCE-ADDRESS");  break;
            case 5: debugIP("CHANGED-ADDRESS");  break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    die("STUN timeout\n");
}
int main(int argn, char **argv)
{
    if( argn!=2 ) die("usage: stun_cli <stun_server>\n");
    int sockfd= connect_to_host(argv[1], "3478", SOCK_DGRAM);
    stun_req(sockfd, mypeer);
}
```

Список бесплатных STUN-серверов можно взять [с Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN#.D0.9F.D1.83.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_STUN-.D1.81.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B).

Comment: Спасибо вам огромнейшее. Скажите, могу ли, раз вы уже отвлеклись на мой вопрос (а мне будет неудобно побеспокоить вас в другие время), попросить вас подсказать пару моментов, смежных данному? То есть вопросу получения клиентами своих внешних IP:порт'ов.. Первое, что хотел бы спросить у вас: а каким образом в вашем примере пробивается каскадный (т.е. 2-й NAT) с каждой из сторон при том, что вы не шлёте UPnP запрос?.. По мне так это колдовство какое-то. Здесь нужно или UPnP (NAT-PNP) или туннелировать по ICMP манёврами близкими к хакингу.. А у вас-то как это получается?

Comment: Вы простите, пример ваш у меня не получается собрать под Windows 10 x64, т.е. на Winsock2, а так бы я потестил. Хотя, в любом случае, вы крайне обязали бы меня, если бы согласились немножко прокомментировать код вашего приложения (которое на https://github.com/sercxjo/nathole-example), в этом случае, без преувеличения скажу, что ваш пост тут был бы ярчайшим и полезнейшим за все последние годы. Вопрос "пиринговой свободы" (начисто разбивающийся об каскадные и симметричные NAT'ы) сегодня едвали не _самый_ виртуозный вопрос, как сетевого программирования, так, пожалуй, и IT вообще.. Прошу вас.

Comment: @aversilov, Пример под linux gcc, попробуйте mingw.
Оба пира начинают передачи пакетов одновременно по ответу от сигнального сервера, у которого должен быть белый IP, оповещающего их об адресах и портах друг друга. Первые пакеты не доходят до адресатов, так как они не ожидаются их NAT-ами, но после прохождения через NAT исходящего пакета, он начинает пропускать входящие. Тут главное угадать порт. Если внешний порт не меняется при передаче на разные IP, то это просто.

Comment: Сергей, будьте добры, скажите: 1) под "угадать" вы имели в виду _синхронизацию_? То есть пиры должны начать "стучаться" по некоему заранее условленному между них расписанию, правильно я понимаю? А какова в таком случае ширина разбежки, позволительной для них? Насколько они имеют право рассинхронизоваться, чтобы не пропал keep-alive, удерживаемый поверх NAT'ов этой "силой инерции пропускания" (о которой вы сказали, - т.е. если внутрб пропустил раз, то дальше уж и вовне..)

Comment: 2) по поводу "расписания": вы предлагаете это расписание виртуально, так сказать, организовать им через STUN, не так ли? А не будет ли само вмешательство STUN'а приводить в случае с симметрическими NAT к тому, что "рулетка" слепого выбора портов будет по-новой задавать порт? (именно таким сценарием ,как вам известно, на всех форумах и во всех хабрастатьях и пугают). Как быть в этом случае? Предполагаете ли вы использование TURN сервера или множественные пакеты-кандидаты (как в ICE)? Если да, то можете ли вы показать хоть минимальный образчик, как это сделать (в коде)?

Comment: 3) Вы, очевидно, профессионал с существенным стажем и должно быть вы владеете статистикой или просто информацией о положении дел в этом вопросе на текущий год: скажите, ушли ли в прошлое повсеместные "симметрические NAT"? А также: насколько часто вместо 1 NAT с каждой стороны стоят 2 (так наз. "каскадные"), не уходит ли с арены и эта практика? И то же ли самое имеет место быть в случае с пирами, которые будут сидеть на 2G/3G/4G мобильном интернет-канале? Код, приведённый вами, одинаково большие шансы помочь имеет и для этих (mobile) пиров?

Comment: 4) И не будете ли вы так любезны всё-таки объяснить мне, почему вы в своём решении отошли от весьма популярного в этом сегменте вопросов использования UPnP? Потому ли, что - по вашим сведениям - UPnP в чрезвычайно большом проценте реальных случаев отрублен на NAT'ах провайдеров и, особенно, на NAT'ах провайдеров мобильного интернета? Или есть другие причины, почему вы решили, что UPnP/NAT-PMP тут подойдёт меньше?

Comment: @aversilov, 1) я имел в виду, что порт может отличаться при отправке на STUN и отправке второму пиру, и в этом случае второй пир не угадает его, NAT второго пира будет ожидать входящие пакеты не по тому порту и не пробьётся. Это так называемый симметричный NAT.

Comment: 2) Расписания нет, просто входящий пакет должен прийти втечение какого-то таймаута, установленного в роутере, после исходящего (думаю он должен быть по крайней мере несколько секунд). В моей программе пир посылает пакет, до 300мс ждёт ответа, если приходит ошибка по ICMP, ждёт ещё 150мс,  повторяет ожидание пакета пока не вычитает все входящие пакеты, и снова посылает пакет. Т.е. отправка происходит через 300мс после последнего принятия пакета или 450 после ICMP-ошибки. Таймаут и  задержку нужно подобрать экспериментально.

Comment: 3) Нет у меня статистики, это мой первый опыт по пробитию NAT. Один пир был за домашним роутером, другой через wifi от смартфона с симкой МТС. И там и там оказался port restricted NAT.
4) Мне было задание использовать именно такой способ да и UPnP на моём роутере как оказалось не работает, не смотря что вроде "включено". К тому же UPnP не подойдёт для 3G/4G, у них там обычно свой NAT уже есть, а тут ещё NAT в смартфоне, каскадный получается.

Comment: Цитата: _другой через wifi от смартфона с симкой МТС_
О, вот это как раз и мой случай. У меня точно так же второй пир - ноут с Wi-Fi точки, расшаренной смартфоном, и тоже провайдер 3G МТС. Смотрите, какое совпадение..

Comment: Но, прошу прощения, всё-таки (как я заметил уже второй раз) вы избегаете начисто упоминания UPnP (протокол IGD) и NAT-PMP.. Почему? Какое соображение этому препятствует? Что не так с этим стеком технологий мапинга портов?

Comment: И позвольте сразу спрошу вторую, весьма важную, согласитесь, вещь: если на пути 4 NAT', т.е. по 2 с каждой стороны (даже если таковые не symmetric), то сохраняется правота вашего подхода - "первый пробный пакет" - или нет? Пробьёт ли каскадный/двойной NAT такая же техника? Если есть какие-то тут отличия и необходимые дополнительные манипуляции, то не могли бы вы их подсказать?..

Comment: Каскадный NAT пробивается, если среди каскада нет симметричного NAT. Я не избегаю UPnP, просто ещё не изучал этот вопрос.

Comment: То есть, я просто проговорю чётко, повторив ваш ответ, чтобы всё стало окончательно на свои места: та техника, которая имплементирована в вашем коде, пробивает и _одинарый_, и любое количество _выстроенных в каскад_ NAT'ов - что с одной стороны находящихся, что с обеих (при условии, что НИГДЕ, ни на одной стороне нет НИ ОДНОГО экземпляра симметрического NAT). Это очень важно. Подтвердите, если я в точности правильно повторил. А если нет, поправьте меня детально, прошу вас.

Comment: @aversilov, да рассчитано на это, но надо проверять. С симметричным NAT с *одной* стороны можно попробовать, но надо уже модифицировать программу.

Comment: Сергей, скажите, а вам эта задача в данный момент интересна/актуальна? Вы сейчас, сами по себе я имею в виду, планируете ли развить эту программу, код которой привели? Если да, то могу расшарить вам мою библиотеку на GoogleDisk по данному вопросу, там сотни примеров и переводов (моих лично, эксклюзивных) с английского, немецкого, французского и испанского статей и обсуждений с форумов по всему миру - всё по этой теме: пробивка NAT, пиринговые и full distributed сети, торренты, оверлейные сети, сетевой хакинг, туннелирование по "сторонним" протоколам и т.п. Специально долго собирал.

Comment: P.S. Я вам выслал приглашение в скайп (на оба - и на sergej.digitalguard и на hlutchinsvmail.ru), мой Skype: aversilov. Вы не будете против пообщаться?

Answer (score 1):

Не C++, а pуthon код, но он лишь для объяснения.

```
import socket
import threading
import binascii

source_ip = "0.0.0.0"
source_port = 27035

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((source_ip, source_port))

def read_chat(sock):
    while True:
       data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)
       print('\r', addr,"<", data)

reader = threading.Thread(target=read_chat,args=(sock,))
reader.start()

remote = "stun.l.google.com", 19302

line = "000100001EB4519209521FCF7477D69F91ABA270"
bline = binascii.a2b_hex(line)
print(line)
sock.sendto(bline, remote)
```

Как видите, это самый типичный socket, где я отправляю хитрый запрос на **stun.l.google.com:19302**.

Как его сформировать? Самый полный ответ вы найдёте в исходниках [pystun3](https://pypi.org/project/pystun3/).

Но если вкратце, разобьём строку на группы по 4 элемента:
**0001 0000 1EB4 5192 0952 1FCF 7477 D69F 91AB A270**

Что это? Зачем? Запрос по протоколу. Читайте исходники по ссылке выше или читайте [rfc5389](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5389).

**0001** - BindRequestMsg, тип запроса.

**0000** - размер данных при передаче, но мы ничего не передаем.

А все остальные **32** элемента просто **рандомные** значения от 0 по F.

Код для формирования запроса

```
import random    

BindRequestMsg = '0001'
send_data = ""
str_len = "%#04d" % (len(send_data) / 2)
tranid = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for i in range(32))
str_data = ''.join([BindRequestMsg, str_len, tranid, send_data])
print(str_data)

arr = bytes(str_data, 'ascii')
z = list(arr)
print(z)
```